# Compressing a string PHP

Tags: php

Let's say an input a string

`$a=aabbbc`

`$b=abbcabb`

the expected output should be:
for

```
$a = 2a3bc

$b = a2bca2b
```

here is my code:

```
function lineEncoding($s) {

    $string = str_split($s);
    $counter = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($string);$i++){
        $counter = substr_count($s, $string[$i]);
            if($string[$i]==$string[$i+1]){
                $stringConverted .= $counter . $string[$i];
            } else if($counter==1){
                $stringConverted .= $string[$i];
            } else {
                $i++;
            }
    }
    return $stringConverted;
}
```

I get an output for `$a = 2a3b` But it should be `2a3bc`

```
$b = null
```

but I should've get

```
a2bca2b
```

Comment: There is no logic on what you want to output ? can you explain us what is the logic ?

Comment: First, the string is divided into the least possible number of disjoint substrings consisting of identical characters
for example, "aabbbc" is divided into ["aa", "bbb", "c"]

Next, each substring with length greater than one is replaced with a concatenation of its length and the repeating character
for example, substring "bbb" is replaced by "3b"

Finally, all the new strings are concatenated together in the same order and a new string is returned.

Comment: I seems like RLE-algorithm.. but I didn't understand why $a='aabbc' should be '2a3bc' (I guess it would be '2a2bc') :-/

Comment: SORRY TYPO :O. It should've been 3 b's.

Comment: Check out the link: [https://3v4l.org/mU0av](https://3v4l.org/mU0av)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function line_encoding($e){
    $s = preg_split("//",$e);
    $s[-1] = "";
    $o = 1;
    $f = "";
    for($c=0;$c<strlen($e);$c++){
        if($s[$c]==$s[$c-1]){
            $o++;
        }else{
            $f .= $o==1?$s[$c-1]:($o.$s[$c-1]);
            $o=1;
        }
    }
    return $f;
}
```

Check if this works

Comment: This seems to work: `abbcabb` produces `a2bca2b` which is what OP is expecting

Comment: Note that you can iterate on a string with `for`, when accessing each character this way: `$string[$offset]`. Also, I'm not sure using `count()` in the `for` loop is relevant: it will execute it each time, whereas the string length does not change. Use a variable instead.

Comment: Or use `foreach`, since you're iterating on an array.

Comment: Using strlen will be a good suggestion. But not using foreach because I would need to track values of diff. index, which is much troublesome

Comment: Check my answer [https://3v4l.org/mU0av](https://3v4l.org/mU0av)

Comment: And how foreach prevents you to use previous value? `foreach ($s as $offset => $character)`. Then just check with `$s[$offset - 1]` when `$offset > 0`

Comment: well done. nice one.

Answer (score 2):

we don't need to use any splitters and regexps.. I guess it will make the function slower..

```
<?php
$a='aabbbc';
$b='abbcabb';
echo $a.' - '.lineEncoding($a).PHP_EOL;
echo $b.' - '.lineEncoding($b).PHP_EOL;

function lineEncoding($s) {
    $l = strlen($s); // calculate strlen instead of
                     // using function into the for-loop
                     // for performance purpose
    $r = '';     // result
    $c = 1;      // duplicate counter
    $o = $s[0];  // first character
    for ($i=1; $i<$l; ++$i) { // starting analyze from second character
        if ($s[$i] == $o) {
            // we have duplicate in a row
            ++$c;
        } else {
            // duplicates ends, form result string
            // if counter == 1, just put the character w/o counter
            $r .= ($c>1) ? $c.$o : $o;
            // save character last found for further analyze
            $c = 1;
            $o = $s[$i];
        }
    }
    // put the last character(s) into the result
    $r .= ($c>1) ? $c.$o : $o;
    return $r;
}
```

output:

```
aabbbc - 2a3bc
abbcabb - a2bca2b
```

Comment: I like this one more.

Comment: without s?  my edited answer was not bad but some people down again.

Comment: well answer carry on.