# String compression in php

Tags: php

Here is my input

```
aaaabbaaaababbbcccccccccccc
```

And this is my expected output

```
a4b2a4b1a1b3c12
```

I tried like doing `foreach` and then `concating` the count of values. It seems like brutforcing. Is there any way to do it efficiently in php .

Help pls

Comment: What would be the reason for downvote ?

Comment: Please add the code which you have attempted to use

Comment: Ok, i will update the the question with code i have so far

Comment: Are you interested in a programming exercise for this particular string? Or do you really want a generalised compression algorithm? What if the input contains numbers itself? Does the compressed string `12` mean `11` or `12`?

Comment: @deceze the input will be strictly alphabets

Comment: If I understand what you're doing, this would double the size of the alphabet rather than compress it ... `a1b1c1d1e1f1g1 ... z1` ?! Pretty much *any* natural language string is going to end up far bigger than the original ... this doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: The logic was like this. .a comes 4 times so a4, b comes 2 times so b4, then a comes 4 times so a4.. like this..

Comment: In some form or another you *do* have to use a loop to go through each character... You can probably express "match consecutive equal characters" as a regex and then replace them with a callback... but that would still iterate the string character by character with some horrific backtracking internally.

Comment: https://eval.in/599018

Comment: Yeah, iterating is the only way, so should i iterate and compare with the previous value and do the count like that .. ?

Comment: @splash58 That was awesome ! Let me read your code, deep once again. It works great

Comment: As a bare minimum, you can't know the answer for a particular string until you've read through the entire string at least once. This means any algorithm will have a lower bound complexity Omega(n). If that's what you're getting you probably can't do any better.

Comment: definitely [duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365494/compressing-a-string-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to get the result

```
preg_match_all('/(.)\1*/', $str, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$m = array_map(function($i) { return $i[1] . strlen($i[0]); } , $m);
echo implode('', $m);   // a4b2a4b1a1b3c12
```

[demo](http://eval.in/599018)

Comment: Thanks, It would be helpful, if you explain how i can do this in for loop

Comment: You want replace array_map to loop ? Or about what is your questoin?

Comment: Yeah, just to know how it would be if i do loop

Comment: `foreach ($m as &$i) $i = $i[1] . strlen($i[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do it with a few for loops (encoding and decoding):

```
$input = 'aaaabbaaaababbbcccccccccccc';
$encoded = SillyEncoding::encode($input);
$decoded = SillyEncoding::decode($encoded);

echo "input = \t", var_export($input, true), "\n";
echo "encoded = \t", var_export($encoded, true), "\n";
echo "decoded = \t", var_export($decoded, true), "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
input =         'aaaabbaaaababbbcccccccccccc'
encoded =       'a4b2a4b1a1b3c12'
decoded =       'aaaabbaaaababbbcccccccccccc'
```

**The `SillyEncoding` class:**

```
class SillyEncoding
{
    private static $digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    static function encode($string)
    {
        $output = '';

        if (strlen($string) > 0) {
            $count = 0;
            $char = $string[0];

            for ($i = 0; isset($string[$i]); ++$i) {
                if (isset(self::$digits[$string[$i]])) {
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The input string must not contain a digit at offset %d, got "%s"', $i, $string[$i]));
                }

                if ($string[$i] === $char) {
                    ++$count;
                } else {
                    $output .= "{$char}{$count}";
                    $count = 1;
                    $char = $string[$i];
                }

                if (!isset($string[$i + 1])) {
                    $output .= "{$char}{$count}";
                }
            }
        }

        return $output;
    }

    static function decode($string)
    {
        $output = '';
        $length = strlen($string);

        if ($length > 0) {
            $char = $string[0];
            $count = null;

            if ($length < 2) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Input string must be empty or at least 2 bytes long, got %d bytes', $length));
            }

            if (isset(self::$digits[$string[0]])) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Input string must not start with a digit, got "%s"', $string[0]));
            }

            for ($i = 1; isset($string[$i]); ++$i) {
                $isDigit = isset(self::$digits[$string[$i]]);

                if ($isDigit) {
                    $count .= $string[$i];
                }

                if (!$isDigit || !isset($string[$i + 1])) {
                    if (null === $count) {
                        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Expected a digit at offset %d, got "%s"', $i, $string[$i]));
                    }

                    $count = (int) $count;

                    for ($j = 0; $j < $count; ++$j) {
                        $output .= $char;
                    }

                    $char = $string[$i];
                    $count = null;
                }
            }
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

---

A few things to note:

- this isn't an efficient compression algorithm - it might reduce the size if there are many repeated characters, but if you feed it "normal" text the output will be about twice the size of the input
- the input cannot contain any digits whatsoever (OP: "*the input will be strictly alphabets*")

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = str_split('aaaabbaaaababbbcccccccccccc');
$count = 0;
$a=$result=$b='';

for ($i=0; $i <= count($str); $i++) {
  if($a==$str[$i]){
    $count++;
    $result = $a.$count;
  } else{
    if ($count > 0) {
      $b .= $result;
    }
    $count = 1;
    $a = $str[$i];
    $result = $a.$count;
  }

}
print_r($b);
```

See [result](https://eval.in/599135)